# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'media' when implementing a gif generator for my discord bot

Tags: python, keyerror

I am currently attempting to implement a discord bot into my server through Visual Studio Code as an extracurricular project of mine and I want to add a command that allows the bot to generate gifs. I am doing this through a tenor API, and I have followed a few other tutorials and have seen similar stack overflow questions to mine. After looking over them this is what I've worked out so far.

```
import requests
import discord


from discord.ext import commands

TenorToken=str('TenorToken')
DiscordToken=str('DiscordToken')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as '+ bot.user.name +'!')

def get_gif(searchTerm):
    r=requests.get("https://tenor.googleapis.com/v2/search?q=%s&key=%s&client_key=%s&limit=%s"%(searchTerm, TenorToken,DiscordToken,1))
    data=r.json()

    for result in data['results']:
        print('- result -')
        #print(result)
    
        for media in result['media']:
            print('- media -')
            #print(media)
            #print(media['gif'])
            print('url:', media['gif']['url'])
    
    return data['results'][0]['media'][0]['gif']['url']

@bot.command(name='gif')
async def on_message(ctx,arg):
    gif_url=get_gif(arg)

    embed=discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=gif_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(DiscordToken)
```

After running my bot in my server, I will type in my command and an error will return telling me

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'media'`

I can't seem to find any tutorials using ctx or the ones that do don't apply to what I'm trying and at the moment I am somewhat lost as to what I need to do next. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like indentation is bad at: `for media in result['media']:`

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I changed my indentation but the issue still persists